# Underscore _.bind() issue with nested function calls

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

After using `_.bindAll('addOne')`, the `addOne`method does get a correct `this` but it somehow breaks function calls on other objects inside this "bound" method :

```
/**
 * Add an element to the list
 */
addOne: function(tag) {

    // scope of this is correct
    var newClass = App.getViewClass('myClass')(someOptions) <-- scope inside App::getViewClass is wrong! overriden by current this

}
```

Any ideas on how i could somehow restore normal behavior?

Comment: You can start by making your question a little clearer...maybe a little more context?

Comment: Yes how exactly are you calling "bindAll"?  It takes more than one parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to wrap my getter :

```
var myObject = new (App.getModelClass(model))(data);
```

As i got incorrect scope with :

```
var myObject = new App.getModelClass(model)(data);
```